# Find the maximum height, distance from the launching point and the time in which a rocket has been flying?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

A rocket is thrown at an angle of $53$  $degrees$ with the surface of Earth, with initial velocity $100 m/s$ and initial acceleration 30 $m/s^2$. The engine works only for $3$ seconds then rocket acts like a free body. Find:

1) Maximum height that the rocket reaches

2) The distance from it's launching point it performs

3) Find the time it has spend flying

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange. Note that we are not a homework help-site. Homework questions are only on-topic if they show effort on your part **and** are about physical concepts rather than "check-my-work"-type or "which formulas to use"-type.